# How to manually invoke gesture recognizer registered with RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

In my code I do it like this:

```
let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
mainView.messagesView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
_ = recognizer.rx.event.bind { _ in
    self.mainView.dismissKeyboard()
}.disposed(by: bag)
```

But now I need to test it:

```
func testIfKeyboardIsDismissedAfterMessageViewWasTapped() {
    let view = ThreadView()
    let model = StubThreadViewModel()
    let controller = ThreadViewController(view: view, viewModel: model)
    controller.viewDidLoad()
    let window = UIWindow()
    window.addSubview(view)
    view.textView.becomeFirstResponder()
    XCTAssertTrue(view.textView.isFirstResponder) //TRUE, test passes
    view.messageView. //Here I dont know how to force tap manually
    XCTAssertFalse(view.textView.isFirstResponder) //FALSE, test fails
}
```

Comment: You don't need to test whether gesture recognizers work. Just test your `dismissKeyboard()` method directly.

Comment: No I need to test if tap dismiss the keyboard;-)

Comment: No you don't. If your dismiss keyboard works, then all you need to "test" is that the recognizer is attached to the correct view and bound to the dismiss function. That can be done with a regex. Frankly to my view, it goes in the category of "don't bother."

Comment: I agree with @DanielT. . What you're trying to do belongs in a Integration Test / UI Test, and even then I wouldn't test a keyboard dismissal as its too fragile. There is no need to test already-tested UIKit concepts. 

The only thing I'd test is that the even is properly emitted.

Comment: @DanielT., You said "all you need to "test" is that the recognizer is attached to the correct view and bound to the dismiss function".  This is what I want to achieve;) How can I test it?

Comment: This could do it: https://github.com/apple/swift-syntax or just use a regex on the file.

Answer (score 0):

`UIView` has a property `gestureRecognizers` which lets you get all recognizers on the view. You can use that to change the state of the recognizer and that should work? Something along the below lines

```
UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRec = view.messagesView.gestureRecognizers.firstObject;
gestureRec.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged;
gestureRec.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded;
```

EDIT - this will only work in async mode since the event would be triggered in the next runloop. Looks like the only way to trigger it forcibly and synchronously (async tests are nasty!) would be to put in a hack - something like [this](https://github.com/darjeelingsteve/gesture-testing/blob/master/Gesture%20TestingTests/SwipeViewTests.m#L67)

**NOTE** - do not use that code while shipping!

Comment: This property is `get-only` for Swift 4.1